# How to understand a mutable borrow of an immutable borrow with the same lifetimes?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm having a hard time understanding this snippet:

```
fn main() {}

fn f<'a>(mem: &'a mut &'a u8) {}

fn dp<'a>(mem: &'a mut &'a u8) {
    f(mem);
    f(mem);
}
```

The error message says:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*mem` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:7:7
  |
5 | fn dp<'a>(mem: &'a mut &'a u8) {
  |       -- lifetime `'a` defined here
6 |     f(mem);
  |     ------
  |     | |
  |     | first mutable borrow occurs here
  |     argument requires that `*mem` is borrowed for `'a`
7 |     f(mem);
  |       ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I know this `&'a mut &'a u8` thing is incorrect, but why is the error message like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&mut T` is invariant over `T`. Here, in your case `T` is `&u8`. The problem is that the inner and outer lifetimes are same. The inner lifetime `'a` is "some" lifetime  greater than (or atleast as long as) the duration of the function `dp()`, but since it is behind a mutable reference it cannot be shortened to the duration of the function `f()` (remember `&mut T` is invariant over `T`). But the mutable reference (outer) is also `'a`, as a result `*mem` will stay borrowed (`&mut T` is always reborrowed i.e `&mut *T` when being passed to a function) after the first call to `f()`. Hence the second call fails, since `*mem` is already borrowed. You can fix this by using different (i.e disjoint) inner & outer lifetimes.

You can read more about variance and lifetimes [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance).

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out myself! But this is a useful answer anyway!