# Borrowed value sent to a function does not live long enough in a Rust program

Tags: rust, rusqlite

I try to send a `rusqlite` Statement by mutable reference to a function, to let that function execute a query and pack the results into a Peekable Iterator. The compiler complains that the statement that I borrow does not live long enough.

The following program works, if I remove the comments and use **alt. 2** instead of **alt.1 **.

```
use std::iter::Peekable;

use rusqlite::{
    Error,
    MappedRows,
    Row,
    Statement,
    params,
};

fn get_mapped_rows<'stmt>(get_stmt: &'stmt mut Statement<'stmt>,
)-> Peekable<MappedRows<'stmt, impl FnMut(&Row<'_>) -> Result<i64, Error>>> {
    get_stmt
        .query(params![0, 0])
        .unwrap()
        .mapped(|row| {
            Ok(row.get(0)?)
        })
        .peekable()
}

fn main() {
    let conn = rusqlite::Connection::open("db.sqlite3")
        .unwrap();

    let mut get_stmt = conn
        .prepare("SELECT dbl_time FROM log")
        .unwrap();

    // Alt. 1
    let mut mapped_rows = get_mapped_rows(&mut get_stmt);

    /*
    // Alt. 2
    let mut mapped_rows = get_stmt
        .query(params![0, 0])
        .unwrap()
        .mapped(|row| {
            let nbr: i64 = row.get(0)?;
            Ok(nbr)
        })
        .peekable();
     */

    while let Some(row_result) = mapped_rows.next() {
        match row_result {
            Ok(dbl_time) => { println!("dbl_time:{} is_last:{}",
                                       dbl_time,
                                       mapped_rows.peek().is_none()); },
            _ => panic!("Error!"),
        }
    }
}
```

I would have expected the iterator returned by `get_mapped_rows` to be dropped before `get_stmt` and therefore I do not understand how the lifetime of the borrowed `get_stmt` becomes a problem.

However the compiler says:

```
error[E0597]: `get_stmt` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:31:43
   |
26 |     let mut get_stmt = conn
   |         ------------ binding `get_stmt` declared here
...
31 |     let mut mapped_rows = get_mapped_rows(&mut get_stmt);
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
53 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `get_stmt` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `get_stmt` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `Statement`
```

**Edit:**
Originally I tried to pass two different statements into the function:

```
fn get_rows<'stmt>(
    i: u32,
    get_stmt_0: &'stmt mut Statement<'_>,
    get_stmt_1: &'stmt mut Statement<'_>,
) -> Rows<'stmt> {
    let stmt = if i < 42 {
        get_stmt_0
    } else {
        get_stmt_1
    };

    stmt
        .query(params![0, 0])
        .unwrap()
}
```

Using `&'stmt mut Statement<'_>` here leads to another problem with the compiler saying:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
9  |     get_stmt_0: &'stmt mut Statement<'_>,
   |     ---------- has type `&mut Statement<'1>`
10 |     get_stmt_1: &'stmt mut Statement<'_>,
   |     ---------- has type `&mut Statement<'2>`
...
13 |         get_stmt_0
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of a mutable reference to `Statement<'_>`
   = note: mutable references are invariant over their type parameter
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance

error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
9  |     get_stmt_0: &'stmt mut Statement<'_>,
   |     ---------- has type `&mut Statement<'1>`
10 |     get_stmt_1: &'stmt mut Statement<'_>,
   |     ---------- has type `&mut Statement<'2>`
...
15 |         get_stmt_1
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ assignment requires that `'2` must outlive `'1`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of a mutable reference to `Statement<'_>`
   = note: mutable references are invariant over their type parameter
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance
```

Here I say that both input statements and the return value should share the same lifetime. Somehow the compiler indicates that they have different types (different lifetimes `'1` and `'2` respectively). What does that mean? And any ideas on how to fix that?

**Edit 2**
Trying to introduce another lifetime parameter for the input `Statements` called `'a`. Function now looks like:

```
fn get_rows<'stmt, 'a>(
    i: u32,
    get_stmt_0: &'a mut Statement<'_>,
    get_stmt_1: &'a mut Statement<'_>,
) -> Rows<'stmt> where 'a: 'stmt
{
    let stmt = if i < 42 {
        get_stmt_0
    } else {
        get_stmt_1
    };

    stmt
        .query(params![0, 0])
        .unwrap()
}
```

From what I understand I now state (using the `where` clause) that the lifetime of the `Statements` must be at least as long as that of the returned `Rows`. But I still get the same error as before:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
9  |     get_stmt_0: &'a mut Statement<'_>,
   |     ---------- has type `&mut Statement<'1>`
10 |     get_stmt_1: &'a mut Statement<'_>,
   |     ---------- has type `&mut Statement<'2>`
...
14 |         get_stmt_0
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of a mutable reference to `Statement<'_>`
   = note: mutable references are invariant over their type parameter
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance

error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
9  |     get_stmt_0: &'a mut Statement<'_>,
   |     ---------- has type `&mut Statement<'1>`
10 |     get_stmt_1: &'a mut Statement<'_>,
   |     ---------- has type `&mut Statement<'2>`
...
16 |         get_stmt_1
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ assignment requires that `'2` must outlive `'1`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of a mutable reference to `Statement<'_>`
   = note: mutable references are invariant over their type parameter
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance
```

I honestly don't understand if the problem has to do with lifetimes or with selecting between two different input references.

Comment: `&'a mut X<'a>` (almost?) always is wrong, and so it is here, should be `&'stmt mut Statement<'_>`

Comment: `Ok(row.get(0)?)` why not `row.get(0)` there doesn't seem to be a error conversion necessary.

Comment: There are a bunch of questions on the topic already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73654520/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201992/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76872240/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081272/ not sure if any of these are close enough to be considered a dupe.

Comment: Your first comment actually fixed this particular problem, not that I understand why. I have been looking for a good explanation for the difference between lifetime annotations in different places in function signatures.

Comment: I simplified my original problem before posting it here. What I used to try was a little more complicated, actually passing 2 different rusqlite::Statement parameters into the function and other parameters to help select which one of the statements to actually query. When I tried using `&'stmt mut Statement<'_>` for both of those I get mutual "lifetime may not live long enough" problems instead.

Comment: In very short, the inner lifetime has to outlive the outer one, so they can't realistically be the same, but reusing the same lifetime forces them to be the same because `&mut T` is invariant in `T`

Comment: For your more complex problem you'd just introduce another lifetime parameter and use that for all the `Statements`, the additional lifetime might also need to be tied to some output.

Comment: I added a new *Edit 2* section where I tried to do what I think you suggested. Still get the same compiler error.

Comment: I said use it for the statements, not the references to them, replace `'_` with `'a`, not `'stmt` that's the lifetime the compiler is complaining about to begin with cause it elides different lifetimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about the lifetime *within the `Statement`s* being different, not the lifetime of the references. You need a separate lifetime to convey to the compiler that they are the same rather than leaving it to infer different lifetimes by using `'_`. This compiles:

```
use rusqlite::{params, Rows, Statement};

fn get_rows<'a, 'stmt>(
    i: u32,
    get_stmt_0: &'stmt mut Statement<'a>,
    get_stmt_1: &'stmt mut Statement<'a>,
) -> Rows<'stmt> {
    let stmt = if i < 42 {
        get_stmt_0
    } else {
        get_stmt_1
    };

    stmt.query(params![0, 0]).unwrap()
}
```